# Amplitude and Phase analysis

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft, jupyter-notebook

I have some problem with data analysis. I have a large amount of data written as follows:

```
-0,30273438;-0,06835938;
-0,29785156;-0,05371094;
-0,28320313;-0,04882813;
-0,28808594;-0,06347656;
-0,27343750;-0,03417969;
-0,24414063;-0,03906250;
-0,24414063;-0,01464844;
```

I wrote a small program for building graphics for 2 vectors:

```
 import csv
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib.dates as mdates
 import numpy as np

 x = []
 y = []

 with open('20283.dat', newline='') as csvfile:
     trash = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
     for row in trash:
         x.append(float(row[0].replace(",", ".")))
         y.append(float(row[1].replace(",", ".")))
 #print(x)
 z = len(x)
 #print(t)
 t = np.arange(z)
 plt.figure(1)
 plt.plot(t,x, label='signal')
 plt.xlabel('timing')
 plt.ylabel('x')
 plt.title('First channel')
 plt.legend()
 plt.figure(2)
 plt.plot(t,y, label='signal')
 plt.xlabel('timing')
 plt.ylabel('y')
 plt.title('Second channel')
 plt.legend()

 plt.show()
```

How do I get the amplitude and phase spectra? And how i can realise сustomizable simple moving average filter (window size, time step, point to start and stop)?

Comment: Learn the maths, read the documentation, look for other libraries if the ones you are using don't have what you need, implement the maths with your own functions, write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python `numpy` and `scipy` is usually the place you'll want to look for linear algebra.

For the moving window functions have a look at `pandas` it is fairly interoperable with `numpy` and extends the `numpy` functionality in useful ways.

https://scipy.org/

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/

http://pandas.pydata.org/